# if constexpr for a switch statement based on a template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I have a template constructed similar to this, that defines code specific for some templates:

```
template <typename T>
class CMyClass : public T
{

template<typename T>
inline void CMyClass<T>::SomeFunc()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, CSpecialClass>)
    {
        DoSpecialClassActions();
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        DoGenericActions();
        //...
    }
}


}
```

But now I'm curious if I can use similar `constexpr` condition in a switch statement? (To add additional `case` statements based on the template.)

Something like this (which does not compile):

```
template<typename T>
inline void CMyClass<T>::SomeSwitchFunc()
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case 1:
            doMsg1();
            //...
            break;
        case 2:
            doMsg2();
            //...
            break;
        //...

        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, CSpecialClass>)
        {
        case 10:
            doMsg10();
            //...
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

PS. I know that I can separate this switch into two, but I don't want to do it, as it will thwart compiler optimization.

Comment: Have you tried? What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: @Hulk: The switch above does not compile.

Comment: it might be helpful to add this information to your question (with the error message).

Comment: I understand that you are concerned about compiler optimzation. I think you should make sure that is indeed an issue in production code before you go down the path you are thinking of.

Comment: Why don’t you move the `if constexpr` in the case?

Comment: @L.F.: Yeah, that might be a good solution since if `constexr` doesn't evaluate then the case statement should be technically discarded during compilation (as an empty one.) I need to try it. Thanks. (The only downside of doing it is that I have to do it for every `case` statement. And I have quite a few of them.)

Comment: You're worried about compiler optimization but have you actually [checked](https://godbolt.org/z/wek9Bf)?

Comment: @Kerndog73: first off, I'm not using `clang`. And yes, I did check. Altho my actual example is much more complex. In it the first `switch` is compiled into a series of range comparisons (`CMP` followed by `JA` or `JB`) each leading to its own jump table, plus some simple jumps after equality comparisons, or `JE`. While the second `switch` (the one under `constexp`) is then presented at the end as its own jump table. (It all obviously depends on the `case` constants too.) So I agree, in the grand scheme of things, it's not such a huge performance loss vs if it was combined into one `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative source at hand, but I fear this is not possible.

the [cppreference page on if-statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) states:

> Labels (goto targets, case labels, and default:) appearing in a substatement of a constexpr if can only be referenced (by switch or goto) in the same substatement.

Answer (score 3):

Reading [[stmt.if]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.if) tells us your code is ill-formed. A case label in a `if constexpr` can only refer to a switch enclosed entirely in the if statement.

> A case or default label appearing within such an if statement shall be
>   associated with a switch statement within the same if statement. A
>   label declared in a substatement of a constexpr if statement shall
>   only be referred to by a statement in the same substatement.

You can't have jumps into discarded statements from outside. But you can label the `if constexpr` itself, if it's any consolation.

Comment: I can see that :) I'm asking how to change it to make it do what I want to achieve there.

Comment: @c00000fd - That's not how your question reads. *"But now I'm curious if I can use similar constexpr condition in a switch statement?"* - it's asking about the possibility, which is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in fact as @Hulk correctly stated. However, don't worry too much about that, as any sufficiently smart compiler will optimize empty statements out and bundle them with the default case. Here's an example:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgJykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBm0gAOqAqETgwe3r4BpClpjgKh4VEssfGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%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%2BaonNoPBLXcjwsCcghFRYTzVioAwVKMkzzMs7heH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQYt0Lh9HilBkMsfQiv4yBVlQJJan4jgAFolquM4QVMSxrDMDRjiWgB1MRaD20yFD46ogoyFwGHcTxWj0EJ5iXPR8nSARJjaPJUjehgBme4bOm6ARegmO6piqGoelmP7AT0MY%2Bg%2BuHoae2HIzWDYtgkcDIM4mKeOOVRKLIpayMkY5gGQZBgwqrwGBtWkIFwQgSFOMxdkjXgcK0ZZVgQa0sHiGlSAIrgNEEtiONIKrdko4j/EkfwyLpLg6TpRIzEozWyNIGC4J4viBKE3CRPEiAkHWAgknJOSIAUpIZOICJWG2QnidJ8nKddMxiLMXhMHwIhFXQPQ2uEURxG60O%2BrUJyhtINliCYJJqv0HGdacnjTPJK2/lQH1XZJsmKapiAabphmPEU7tMOWTnhN5/nhiFiXeCqijiI0PUNF2DWkzpRiuEH6Rde4zgDcErm8OFkBJFltnKIY3YNH8aidskYa2N2XG9bHo3uexjhffTvHd8nnnSDS4g0mcSQgA%3D):

```
#include <cstdio>


volatile int number = 2;

template <bool TestForCase1>
auto test() {
    switch(number) {

        case 0:
            printf("Number was 3\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            if constexpr (TestForCase1) {
                printf("Number was 1\n");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            printf("Number was 2\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Number was 3\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

int main() {
    test<false>();
}
```

You can see in the following assembly (gcc trunk x86 -Os) that the compiler will never check for the case where `number` is 1 and just jump to the default label which I suppose is what people usually want (function is inlined):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Number was 3"
.LC1:
        .string "Number was 2"
main:
        push    rcx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR number[rip]
        cmp     eax, 2
        je      .L2
        cmp     eax, 3
        je      .L3
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L4 ; Jump to default case, case 1 omitted
.L3:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        jmp     .L9
.L2:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
.L9:
        call    puts
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
number:
        .long   2
```

So I think that achieves exactly what you had in mind.